# C++: Maybe you know this pitfall?

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm developing a game. I have a header `GameSystem` (just methods like the game loop, no class) with two variables:
`int mouseX` and `int mouseY`. These are updated in my game loop. Now I want to access them from `Game.cpp` file (a class built by a header-file and the source-file). So, I `#include "GameSystem.h"` in `Game.h`. After doing this I get a lot of compile errors. When I remove the include he says of course:

> `Game.cpp:33: error: ‘mouseX’ was not declared in this scope`
>   `Game.cpp:34: error: ‘mouseY’ was not declared in this scope`

Where I want to access `mouseX` and `mouseY`.

All my `.h` files have Header Guards, generated by Eclipse.
I'm using SDL and if I remove the lines that wants to access the variables, everything compiles and run perfectly (*).

I hope you can help me...

This is the error-log when I `#include "GameSystem.h"` (All the code he is refering to works, like explained by the (*)):

```
In file included from ../trunk/source/domein/Game.h:14,
                 from ../trunk/source/domein/Game.cpp:8:
../trunk/source/domein/GameSystem.h:30: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘*’ token
../trunk/source/domein/GameSystem.h:46: error: variable or field ‘InitGame’ declared void
../trunk/source/domein/GameSystem.h:46: error: ‘Game’ was not declared in this scope
../trunk/source/domein/GameSystem.h:46: error: ‘g’ was not declared in this scope
../trunk/source/domein/GameSystem.h:46: error: expected primary-expression before ‘char’
../trunk/source/domein/GameSystem.h:46: error: expected primary-expression before ‘bool’
../trunk/source/domein/FPS.h:46: warning: ‘void FPS_SleepMilliseconds(int)’ defined but not used
```

This is the code which try to access the two variables:

```
SDL_Rect pointer;
pointer.x = mouseX;
pointer.y = mouseY;
pointer.w = 3;
pointer.h = 3;
SDL_FillRect(buffer, &pointer, 0xFF0000);
```

Comment: Code showing the relevant declarations would be helpful, especially the lines specified in the error message.

Comment: You probably need to show the code in question (GameSystem.h). The errors you're showing *sound* like something fundamental, such as a missing semicolon, but without seeing the code it's awfully hard to guess.

Comment: generally speaking, headers are for declarations that will be shared and bodies are for definitions.  Including bodies in headers is mostly avoided as in using headers multiple times you don't want multiple definitions of the same variables/functions being compiled.  Inline and template are some of the exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `GameSystem` header, don't define those variables as:

```
int mouseX;
int mouseY;
```

instead, you should declare them:

```
extern int mouseX;
extern int mouseY;
```

Then in one of your .cpp files you define them:

```
int mouseX;
int mouseY;
```

The problem with defining them in a header file is that the compiler will try to instantiate them in every single .cpp where you include the header.

Comment: Yes, but that's not the cause of all those errors in the question.

Comment: Indeed that works. Thank you very much! But this way, they are declared in "one of the .cpp" files. Isn't there a way to declare them in my "GameSystem.h"?

Comment: @Troubadour:  Those errors happened because he stopped including the header file to avoid the original error of multiple definition.  It was implied but not shown in the question so it's a bit confusing.

Comment: @Amardeep: Ah, okay. I'm thoroughly confused by the question then because it clearly says these are the errors when the header _is_ included. Well done for working it out! +1.

Comment: Thanks; Does this phenomena has a name? Where can I learn about it?

Comment: Yes, I found it (to declare it in GameSystem): just swap the `extern` keywords.